# What is the best word for a student who gains highest grades in school or university?

Tags: single-word-requests

The best student in a school or university

Comment: "Richest", perhaps?

Comment: When do you mean? While school is in session or at graduation?

Comment: @Spencer at graduation

Comment: The student with the highest academic ranking in his class when the class graduates is the valedictorian.

Comment: The answer in that post is U.S. centric.